# Django - Reverse Engineering the Admin site's "Add Foreign Key" button

Tags: javascript, django, django-models

**TL;DR (Short synopsis):**

I have recreated the admin "Add" button in my own project. However, when I hit "save" on the parent form, it is not recognizing the new select element.

**Whole Story:**

I have that functionality working in my own project... almost. I need help figuring out the last step. As it is now, I have a "+" button, I click it, a popup shows up, I add a new object, hit save, popup closes and that new item is now in my select box and selected - just like the admin page. However, when I hit save on this parent form, I get the error that I've selected an item not in the list. Of course, since the page has reloaded, my new item *is* part of the list and I just hit save again and it works. Of course, I need it to save on the first time!

The basic setup is my Parent model is called `System` and the foreign key model is called `Zone`. The `Zone` model lists how many zones a system has (1 zone,2 zones,10 zones, etc...)

OK, some code:

The "Add" link in the template of the parent form:

`<a href="/systems/zones/new/?popup=1" id="add_id_numZones" onclick="return showAddPopup(this);">Add</a>`

In my `New_Zone` view, after saving the new zone, I check if the `popup` `GET` variable is 1, if so, return a javascript function. Here's the view:

```
        ...
        if form.is_valid():
            f = form.save(commit=False)
            pk_value = f.numOfZones
            form.save()
            obj = Zone_Info.objects.get(numOfZones=pk_value)
            if isPopup == "1":
                return HttpResponse('<script>opener.closeAddPopup(window, "%s", "%s");</script>' % (escape(pk_value), escape(obj)))
        ...
```

And here is my Javascript (largely copied from the admin javascript:

```
function html_unescape(text) {
// Unescape a string that was escaped using django.utils.html.escape.
    text = text.replace(/&lt;/g, '<');
    text = text.replace(/&gt;/g, '>');
    text = text.replace(/&quot;/g, '"');
    text = text.replace(/&#39;/g, "'");
    text = text.replace(/&amp;/g, '&');
    return text;
}

function windowname_to_id(text) {
    text = text.replace(/__dot__/g, '.');
    text = text.replace(/__dash__/g, '-');
    return text;
}


function showAddPopup(triggeringLink, pWin) {
    var name = triggeringLink.id.replace(/^add_/, '');
    href = triggeringLink.href;
    var win = window.open(href, name, 'height=500,width=800,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');
    win.focus();
    return false;
}

function closeAddPopup(win, newID, newRepr) {
    newID = html_unescape(newID);
    newRepr = html_unescape(newRepr);
    var name = windowname_to_id(win.name);
    var elem = document.getElementById(name);
    if (elem) {
        if (elem.nodeName == 'SELECT') {
            var o = new Option(newRepr, newID);
            elem.options[elem.options.length] = o;
            o.selected = true;
        } else if (elem.nodeName == 'INPUT') {
            if (elem.className.indexOf('vManyToManyRawIdAdminField') != -1 && elem.value) {
                elem.value += ',' + newID;
            } else {
                elem.value = newID;
            }
        }
    } else {
        var toId = name + "_to";
        elem = document.getElementById(toId);
        var o = new Option(newRepr, newID);
        SelectBox.add_to_cache(toId, o);
        SelectBox.redisplay(toId);
    }

    win.close();
}
```

I took a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744480/django-admin-relatedobjectlookups-how-does-it-refresh-and-set-the-select-on) question and it seems that I am doing precisely the same thing.

Any ideas on how to get that last step of getting the form to recognize the new select element?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I Figured it Out**

The problem was what I was passing to my `closeAddPopup` javascript function. Essentially, I was passing garbage values.

Here's what I originally had in my `New_Zone` view (which didn't work):

```
    ...
    if form.is_valid():
        f = form.save(commit=False)
        pk_value = f.numOfZones
        form.save()
        obj = Zone_Info.objects.get(numOfZones=pk_value)
        if isPopup == "1":
            return HttpResponse('<script>opener.closeAddPopup(window, "%s", "%s");</script>' % (escape(pk_value), escape(obj)))
    ...
```

It's a pretty stupid mistake on my part (clearly it's late). I was assigning `f` to the field `numOfZones` which I *thought* was the `pk` and sending that to the script.

Now, the working view looks like this:

```
       if form.is_valid():
           obj = form.save()
           pk_value = obj.pk
           if "_popup" in request.REQUEST:
               return HttpResponse('<script>opener.closeAddPopup(window, "%s", "%s");</script>' % (escape(pk_value), escape(obj)))
```

Anyway... thanks to... well, Stackoverflow. I don't think I would have solved the problem without posting the question and rereading my code on stackoverflow.

Comment: can you help me please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69313268/how-to-implement-add-another-to-django-model-form