# Using the "Add Another" button with inline formsets?

Tags: javascript, django, inline-formset

I have figured out how to use the admin style "Add Another" button (which adds a new record of the foreign key and pops it into your current form's select box). Here's [that question/answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7782479/django-reverse-engineering-the-admin-sites-add-foreign-key-button) I am wondering if this is possible with an inline formset where the user can dynamically add additional formsets.

For example, I have an estimate app where the user can select `item`s from a drop down menu. They can add a new inline formset instance and select another `item`. If they cannot find the `item`, I want them to be able to add a new `item` record by clicking the same little `+` symbol I used (and therefore all the same JS code) for all my other forms.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is something that is natively supported, maybe do a google search on django admin tree structure or so.

What you are looking at achieving is essentially a chained menu, might need to build an interface for it